# data.table list join with wildcard in column

Tags: r, join, data.table, wildcard, subset

I would like to subset a data.table by joining rather than vector scanning as described in the data.table vignette on p. 6.

Example:

```
dt <- CJ(ID=c("a", "b", "c"),val1=1:5, val2=9:15)
dt[.("a",5),]     # joining on first two columns works
```

But how can I join on the last two columns and skip the argument for the first column? I did not find any information on this in the vignette or elsewhere. I tried things like

```
dt[.(*,4, 10)]
# Error: unexpected '*' in "dt[.(*"
dt[.(,4, 10)]
# Error in list(, 4, 10) : argument 1 is empty
```

But it does not seem to work. How can I avoid vector scanning (which works, of course):

```
dt[val1==4 & val2==10]
```

and do this by joining?

Comment: You should `setkey` on columns on which you want to perform *binary search*. If you query often on various fields and don't want to re-setkey every time try `idx` function in [dwtools](https://github.com/jangorecki/dwtools) package which allows you to skip the columns using `TRUE`, in your case: `dt[CJI(IDX,TRUE,4,10)]`.

Comment: what's your use case? most of the time when people want to do this is for the wrong reasons

Comment: I think it'd be convenient if `dt[.(, 4, 10)]` would automatically consider all values on the first key column, and I think it's quite straightforward to implement. Will take a look and update if I manage. Thanks!

Comment: @Arun I'm happy that you consider adding this functionality! Could you leave a comment here when it is on Github or CRAN? (In case you didn't consider it yet: it would be perfect if the patch is general, i.e. dt[.( , , 4, 10)] would consider all values in the first and second column if it is a four column data.table and so on)